# Non-enumerable properties

Tags: ember.js

all  instances of `Ember.Object` has non-enumerable properties that start with double underscores like `__ember_meta`,  `__next_super`, `__proto__` and so forth.

They are defined like this

```
 export var META_DESC = {
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  value: null
};

var EMBER_META_PROPERTY = {
  name: '__ember_meta__',
  descriptor: META_DESC
};

//....

obj.__defineNonEnumerable(EMBER_META_PROPERTY);
```

And I have an `Email` value object, on which I tried to replicate this technic

```
// lib/validatable-object.js
import Ember from 'ember';

const SKIP_VALIDATION = {
  name: '__skipValidation',
  descriptor: {
    writable:     true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable:   false,
    value: null
  }
};

export default Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    this.__defineNonEnumerable(SKIP_VALIDATION);
    this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

and  within initialization (inside `init`) everything looks correct

```
Object.keys(this)
["address", "label"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)
["__ember1440930504837", "__nextSuper", "__ember_meta__", "address", "label", "__skipValidation"]
```

but not later, when I try to save a model with array of the `emails` -  `__skipValidation` is enumerable again :(

```
// inside serialize() function
Object.keys(snapshot._attributes.emails[0])
["address", "label", "__skipValidation"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(snapshot._attributes.emails[0])
["address", "__nextSuper", "__ember1440931027338", "validLabel", "label", "__skipValidation", "__ember_meta__", "validAddress"]
```

How to prevent property from becoming enumerable again?

**UPDATE**:

I changed `configurable: true`, to `configurable: false` and Ember.js throwed error on https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/bdf819565c6dba1728146e69fd8b495c735902e1/packages/ember-metal/lib/watch_key.js#L81

Comment: How you define email attribute in your model?

Comment: `emails: DS.attr('array')`